# What's the easiest way to implement portable current measurement for a ~200W dc motor?

Tags: dc-motor, current-measurement

I'm tinkering with an electronic skateboard build and I'm looking for a way to do some current measurements "on-the-go". What's the easiest way to implement this?

It wouldn't be a part of the final design, I'm just trying to collect real-world power data for my second board revision.

Basically, I'm looking for something like [this DIY power meter/logger](https://youtu.be/lrugreN2K4w?t=376) (pictured below) but for higher currents (up to ~20A to be safe).

[image: DIY power meter/logger]

Would something like [SparkFun's split core current transformer](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11005) (pictured below) combined with a battery powered Arduino work?

[image: SparkFun's split core current transformer]

Comment: Don't design it. Just buy it: https://powerwerx.com/watt-meter-analyzer-inline-dc-powerpole?gclid=CJieuZvY2OICFfQgrQYdy_8ACw

Answer (score 1):

The "split core current transformer" that you linked will only sense AC current. You will need a hall-effect current transducer. I believe they are available in split-core versions. You could certainly design a data acquisition system with a battery-powered Arduino and a hall-effect current transducer.